# Avoiding focus change when selecting range -- Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which creates a sub range from one given, depending on some criteria.
This sub range is then copied at some location, where it forms the data read by a Chart.

The macro is called each time I click a spinner, as this changes the original range and therefore a new sub range needs to be computed.

The procedure works fine, although it is probably very primitive (first coding experience with VBA-Excel). Only point, when I click the spinner to update data and launch the routine, the 'focus' of the Sheet moves from the location of the button, to the beginning of the range the macro works on.

I overcome this by using Application.Goto at the end of the routine, to bring the upper left corner of the window back to where the Chart and the button are.

However, this means that each time I run the macro, the window contents move to the range and then back to where I want it. That is not really elegant, beside potentially causing some sea-sickness ;-)

I was wondering whether I can avoid that, and how.

thanks for any input, code follows.

```
Sub test_copy2()
Dim InRange As Range
Dim c As Range, o As Range, t As Range
Dim r As Integer
Set InRange = Cells.Range("M434:ATF434")
Set o = Cells.Range("L434")
For Each c In InRange
If c.Offset(-219, 0).Value = 8448 Then
   Set t = Application.Union(o, c)
   Set o = t
End If
Next c
o.Copy
InRange(1, 1).Offset(2, -1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Application.Goto Cells.Range("AF456"), Scroll:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need `Pastespecial`? If not then use this and the shifting will not happen `o.Copy InRange(1, 1).Offset(2, -1)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Siddarth. Not sure I understand your question. Once I 'evaluated' the needed range, that is I know which cells satisfy a criterion, then I need to 'phisically' have these cells somewhere else in the sheet, as they are a data set I whish to display.

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

```
Sub test_copy2()
Dim InRange As Range
Dim c As Range, o As Range, t As Range
Dim r As Integer
Set InRange = Cells.Range("M434:ATF434")
Set o = Cells.Range("L434")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In InRange
        If c.Offset(-219, 0).Value = 8448 Then
           Set t = Application.Union(o, c)
           Set o = t
        End If
    Next c
    o.Copy
    InRange(1, 1).Offset(2, -1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Application.Goto Cells.Range("AF456"), Scroll:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Like I mentioned you can either avoid `pastespecial` as shown in `Way1` or if you want values then replace it with code shown in `Way2`

```
o.Copy
InRange(1, 1).Offset(2, -1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

**Way 1**

`o.Copy InRange(1, 1).Offset(2, -1)`

**Way 2**

`InRange(1, 1).Offset(2, -1).Resize(o.Rows.Count, o.Columns.Count).Value = o.Value`

Comment: Thanks Siddhart, I will try Way2 as well, but I guess this will change my InRange, right? I do not want that. Just create /another/ sub range from an existing one.
In principle, however, I guess I can understand your perspective. If I was clever and versed enough, I would not need to *copy* the sub range anywhere, just use it. Maybe to update the Chart using this sub range as my x-values, and another sub range as my y-values.